# _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse) after "return 0"

Tags: c++, debugging

I'm writing a program where I have to write my own string class and a potion class. I know that this run-time error is usually caused when the program is deleting something that wasn't allocated, but it occurs after the 'return 0' in main. I've debugged it line-by-line and tried some things to try and eliminate the run-time error, but nothing has really worked. Is there anybody that can help me out with this?

Here is my code:

```
//Main
#include "Potion.h"
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void TotalCost( Potion ArrayofPotions[5] )
{
    String Currency[4] = {"Platinum", "Gold", "Silver" ,"Copper"};
    int TotalCost[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    int Cost[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};

    for (short i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (short k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        {
            Cost[k] = ArrayofPotions[i].ConvertCost(k);
            TotalCost[k] += Cost[k];

            if ( i != 0 )
                TotalCost[k] = ArrayofPotions[k].CalculateCost(TotalCost[k - 1], TotalCost[k]);
        }
    }
    cout << "\nTotal cost for all potions: ";

    for (short i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        cout << TotalCost[i] << ' ';
        Currency[i].Display();
    }
}

int main()
{
    Potion Haggling("Potion of Haggling", "You haggle for 10% better prices for 30 seconds",
                "Weak", "0.80.0.4.");

    Potion Strength("Draught of Strength", "You can carry 20% more for 300 seconds", 
                "Low", "2.60.5.1.");

    Potion Health("Solution of Health", "You are 30% tougher for 60 seconds",
              "Mild", "2.20.5.1.");

    Potion Stealth("Philter of Stealth", "You are 40% harder to detect for 60 seconds",
               "Moderate", "0.90.5.1.");

    Potion Waterbreathing("Elixir of Waterbreathing", "You can breathe underwater for 60 seconds",
                      "Strong", "2.10.5.0.");

    Potion ArrayOfPotions[5] = {Haggling, Strength, Health, Stealth, Waterbreathing};

    for (short i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        ArrayOfPotions[i].DisplayPotions();

    TotalCost(ArrayOfPotions);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

//String class
class String
{
public:
    String() : m_str(nullptr)
    { }
    String(char chr) : m_str(nullptr)
    {
        m_str = new char;
        *m_str = ch;
    }
    String(char * str)
    {
        if (str != nullptr)
        {
            m_str = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
            strcpy(m_str, str);
        }
    }
    String(const String & copy) : m_str(copy.m_str)
    { }
    String& operator=(const String & rhs)
    {
        if ( this != &rhs )
        {
            delete [] m_str;
            m_str = new char[strlen(rhs.m_str) + 1];
            strcpy(m_str, rhs.m_str);
        }

        return *this;
    }
    ~String()
    {
        delete [] m_str;
    }
    void Display() const
    {
        cout << m_str;
    }
    char * GetStr() const
    {
        return m_str;
    }
    String Upper()
    {
        char * check = this->m_str;

        for (unsigned short i = 0; i < strlen( this->m_str ); i++, check++)
        {
            if ( *check > 96 && *check < 123 )
            {
                *check -= 32;
            }
            else
                m_str = this->m_str;
        }
        return m_str;
    }
private:
    char * m_str;
};

//Potion class

#include "String.h"

class Potion
{
public:    
    Potion() : m_name(nullptr), m_description(nullptr), m_potency(nullptr),
               m_cost(nullptr)
    { }
    Potion(String name, String description, String potency, String cost)
    {
        m_name = name;
        m_description = description;
        m_potency = potency.Upper();
        m_cost = cost;
    }
    Potion(const Potion & copy) : m_name(copy.m_name), m_description(copy.m_description),
                                  m_potency(copy.m_potency), m_cost(copy.m_cost)
    { }
    int ConvertCost(int index)
    {
        int cost = 0;
        char * new_cost = m_cost.GetStr();
        char * temp_string = new char[strlen( new_cost ) + 1];

        strcpy(temp_string, new_cost);

        char * temp = strtok( temp_string, "." );

        for (short k = 0; k != index; k++)
            temp = strtok( NULL, "." );

        cost = atoi( temp );

        delete [] temp_string;

        return cost;
    }
    int CalculateCost(int & cost1, int cost2)
    {
        if (cost > 99)
        {
            cost1++;
            cost2 -= 100;
        }
        return cost2;
    }
    void DisplayPotions()
    {
        String Currency[4] = {"Platinum", "Gold", "Silver" ,"Copper"};
        int cost = 0;

        m_name.Display();
        m_description.Display();
        m_potency.Display();

        for (short i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            cost = ConvertCost(i);

            if (cost != 0)
            {
                cout << ConvertCost(i) << ' ';
                Currency[i].Display();
            }
        }
    }
private:
    String m_name;
    String m_description;
    String m_potency;
    String m_cost;
};
```

I'm sorry it's really long and I left out some of the output formatting, but I really need some help with this.

P.S. My professor wants us to convert the cost from a string to an int and it has to be put in that "0.0.0.0" format. That's why it is written like that.

Comment: `String& operator=(const String & copy) : m_str(copy.m_str)` this is really bad, both instances have the same pointer. You need to do the same as in copy constructor, and don't forget to delete old pointer.

Comment: Don't use numbers like `96` and `132`, use characters like `'a'` and `'z'`. It helps those that, unlike you, haven't memorised the ASCII table. (And you can leave out the `else` brach instead of doing nothing in `m_str = this->m_str;`.)

Comment: Debug the project and look at the execution stack when the assert violation happens. Look for the first item in the stack that is part of your code. It should be a destructor of `String`, calling `delete[]`. That's a clue for you. The memory is being deleted, when that memory was already deleted before.

Comment: The copy constructor/op= was a mistake. I had them backwards but I fixed it.

Comment: @colematthew4 If the copy constructor and assignment op were backwards, why are you testing if `this != &rhs`?  A copy constructor need never test for this.

Comment: I meant I had the code on the wrong function header. It's just checking in the op= if the object being assigned isn't the invoking object.

Comment: @Dialecticus I know it's double deleting memory I'm just not understanding where I went wrong in the program and how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Your assignment operator is broken, as it copies the pointer from the right hand side.
You need to follow the same procedure as in the copy constructor.

By the way, the copy constructor is also broken, as it will fail if `rhs` is empty.

(It's a safer idea to use an empty string in your representation of an empty string (i.e. use `""` instead of `nullptr`).
It saves you from a lot of null checking.)

This constructor is also broken:

```
String(char * str)
{
    if (str != nullptr)
    {
        m_str = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
        strcpy(m_str, str);
    }
}
```

as it leaves `m_str` uninitialised if you pass it `nullptr` - and you do that a lot.

This constructor is also broken:

```
String(char chr) : m_str(nullptr)
{
    m_str = new char;
    *m_str = ch;
}
```

as it doesn't construct a zero-terminated string.

You need

```
m_str = new char[2];
m_str[0] = ch;
m_str[1] = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

As others stated, your constructors are broken.  In addition to this, the assignment operator is also broken in a subtle way.

The easiest way to fix this is move *most* of the assignment operator code to the copy constructor.

```
String(const String & copy) : m_str(new char[strlen(copy.m_str)+1])
{ 
   strcpy(m_str, copy.m_str);
}
```

As to your assignment operator, the flaw is it deletes the memory before `new[]` is called.  What happens if `new[]` throws an exception?  You've destroyed your old data and you have no way to recover the data.

Instead of how you wrote the assignment operator, a better way is this:

```
   #include <algorithm>
   //...
   String& operator=(String rhs)
   {
     std::swap(rhs.m_str, m_str);
     return *this;
   }
```

That was simple, and it works.  It requires a working copy constructor, and working destructor for `String`.  Since you provided these two functions, writing the assignment operator becomes trivial.

See the `copy/swap idiom`:  [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

This also ensures that if `new[]` throws an exception, your original string is not destroyed.  The `std::swap` merely swaps the two items -- if you can't use `std::swap` then write your own function to swap the pointers, as it should be very simple to implement.